# How to set label size using namespace System.Drawing.Printing?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set label size using namespace System.Drawing.Printing. Of Fix size?
I want 6 labels of some size on a page size of 8.5X11

Comment: by label you mean winforms label or simply a Text in a Rectangle

Comment: yes, few text, images in a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

In .net you can use a PrintPage handler for the PrintDocument object. Inside the PrintPage handler, use e.graphics for the printer output. With e.graphics, the location and size is based on 100 pixels per inch, regardless of the printer's resolution. So, for example, if you want 6 evenly spaced labels over 8 inches, you could position them 114 units apart, 100 * 8/(6+1), (plus the location of the first label).

Answer (score 0):

Any thing you want to draw will surely will have the size that you specify when giving parameters to Draw method.. framework is not going to change that.

Comment: but i want specific size, because i want to print on a specific paer of size 8.5X11, having 6 labels of some size, which can be later detached after print, basically having perforations.